# Android Studio freezes at loading screen and won't start.(Windows 10)

Tags: android-studio

I just got a new laptop today and I am trying to get Android Studio working. 
There was no problem installing it and I've got the latest JDK. I also
added the JAVA_HOME variabel to environment variables.

Problem: When starting android studio the loading bar is filled up and then nothing happens and I don't get passed the loading screen. Does anyone recognize this problem and know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, I uninstalled all versions of JDK and JRE that were installed on my computer and then installed the most recent 64 bit version. After that reinstalled Android Studio and now it is working great.